# Python PuLP LP setting constraints in clustering problem

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I need support in setting constraints for a linear optimization problem modelled in PuLP.
**Background:**
There is a product that has a label. The label space is different depending on the product size - max space is known and set.
Each label has languages that are linked to certain countries. So a label = cluster of language country relations. *(Currently number of clusters is manually pre-set for simplification, and can be changed to meet a feasible solution. However, ideally the model needs to identify minimum number of clusters to fulfil stated criteria.)*
Languages need different amount of space on the label.
Furthermore, each country has a set of requirements such as:

- a certain BBD format (best before date);
- a certain production date format;
- a statement of origin, etc.

Countries cannot be linked to more than one cluster.
Countries that do not share the same requirements cannot be clustered together **(this is where I get stuck)** e.g.:

- US cannot be clustered with CA because they have different BBD formats;
- IN cannot be clustered with GB because IN needs a production date on label, while GB does not;
- SG cannot be clustered with AT because they have different statement of origin, even though same BBD and production date formats, etc.

The task is to create an optimization model that will group countries in clusters based on stated constraints. Eventually some clusters will always have one or two countries due to constraints no matter the label space available. At the same time 80% of the countries share the requirements and those need to be clustered based on the limited label space and other maximization goals (like volume per country), at the same time not have the 20% unique clusters mixed in.
*The objective will be set to maximize each cluster based on country volume, or number of selling units, or sales share, etc. (not included in the question).*

**I need help or hint on how to only cluster countries with shared requirements.** I am able to group countries under different clusters, meeting space constraint and maximizing toward whatever, but they are all mixed from requirements perspective.
Below are data elements and their relations and part of my code. Thanks in advance!

```
    CTY=["SG", "AT", "BE", "BG", "CH", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GR", "HR", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LT", "LV", "NL", "NO", "PL", "PT", "RO", "RS", "SE", "SI", "SK", "RU", "US", "PR", "CA", "AU", "NZ", "JP", "IN", "PH", "GB", "CN"]
    language=["EN_GB", "BG_BG", "CS_CZ", "DA_DK", "DE_DE", "EL_GR", "EN_GB", "ES_ES", "FI_FI", "FR_FR", "HR_HR", "HU_HU", "IT_IT", "LT_LT", "LV_LV", "NL_NL", "NO_NO", "PL_PL", "PT_PT", "RO_RO", "SK_SK", "SL_SI", "SR_RS", "SV_SE", "RU_RU", "EN_US", "EN_CA", "FR_CA", "EN_AU", "JA_JP", "EN_AU", "EN_IN", "EN_PH", "ZH_CN"]
    BBD=["DD-MM-YYYY", "DD-ABC-YYYY", "YYYY/AB/DD", "YYYY-MM-DD"]
    production_date=["DD-MM-YYYY", "YYYY-MM-DD", "NO"]
    origin=["FP", "PI", "NO"]
    space=[1, 2, 3]
    max_language_space=5 #Main constraint - maximum allowed space for label. Value can change depending on the size of product.
    clusters=np.arange(1, 12) #Number of clusters are a consequence to meet an optimal solution - aim to have as little number of clusters as possible at an optimal solution.
    CTY_BBD={"SG":"DD-MM-YYYY", "AT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "BE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "BG":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CH":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CY":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CZ":"DD-MM-YYYY", "DE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "DK":"DD-MM-YYYY", "DO":"DD-MM-YYYY", "ES":"DD-MM-YYYY", "FI":"DD-MM-YYYY", "FR":"DD-MM-YYYY", "GR":"DD-MM-YYYY", "HR":"DD-MM-YYYY", "HU":"DD-MM-YYYY", "IE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "IS":"DD-MM-YYYY", "IT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "LT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "LV":"DD-MM-YYYY", "NL":"DD-MM-YYYY", "NO":"DD-MM-YYYY", "PL":"DD-MM-YYYY", "PT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "RO":"DD-MM-YYYY", "RS":"DD-MM-YYYY", "SE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "SI":"DD-MM-YYYY", "SK":"DD-MM-YYYY", "RU":"DD-MM-YYYY", "US":"DD-ABC-YYYY", "PR":"DD-ABC-YYYY", "CA":"YYYY/AB/DD", "AU":"DD-MM-YYYY", "NZ":"DD-MM-YYYY", "JP":"YYYY-MM-DD", "IN":"DD-MM-YYYY", "PH":"DD-ABC-YYYY", "GB":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CN":"YYYY-MM-DD"}
    language_space={"EN_GB":1, "BG_BG":1, "CS_CZ":1, "DA_DK":1, "DE_DE":1, "EL_GR":1, "EN_GB":1, "ES_ES":1, "FI_FI":1, "FR_FR":1, "HR_HR":1, "HU_HU":1, "IT_IT":1, "LT_LT":1, "LV_LV":1, "NL_NL":1, "NO_NO":1, "PL_PL":1, "PT_PT":1, "RO_RO":1, "SK_SK":1, "SL_SI":1, "SR_RS":1, "SV_SE":1, "RU_RU":3, "EN_US":1, "EN_CA":1, "FR_CA":1, "EN_AU":1, "JA_JP":3, "EN_AU":1, "EN_IN":1, "EN_PH":1, "ZH_CN":2}
    CTY_language={"SG":["EN_GB"], "AT":["DE_DE"], "BE":["FR_FR", "NL_NL"], "BG":["BG_BG"], "CH":["DE_DE", "FR_FR"], "CY":["EL_GR"], "CZ":["CS_CZ"], "DE":["DE_DE"], "DK":["DA_DK"], "DO":["ES_ES"], "ES":["ES_ES"], "FI":["FI_FI"], "FR":["FR_FR"], "GR":["EL_GR"], "HR":["HR_HR"], "HU":["HU_HU"], "IE":["EN_GB"], "IS":["FI_FI", "SV_SE"], "IT":["IT_IT"], "LT":["LT_LT"], "LV":["LV_LV"], "NL":["NL_NL"], "NO":["NO_NO"], "PL":["PL_PL"], "PT":["PT_PT"], "RO":["RO_RO"], "RS":["SR_RS"], "SE":["SV_SE"], "SI":["SL_SI"], "SK":["SK_SK"], "RU":["RU_RU"], "US":["EN_US"], "PR":["EN_US"], "CA":["EN_CA", "FR_CA"], "AU":["EN_AU"], "NZ":["EN_AU"], "JP":["JA_JP"], "IN":["EN_IN"], "PH":["EN_PH"], "GB":["EN_GB"], "CN":["ZH_CN"]}
    CTY_production_date={"SG":"DD-MM-YYYY", "AT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "BE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "BG":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CH":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CY":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CZ":"DD-MM-YYYY", "DE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "DK":"DD-MM-YYYY", "DO":"DD-MM-YYYY", "ES":"DD-MM-YYYY", "FI":"DD-MM-YYYY", "FR":"DD-MM-YYYY", "GR":"DD-MM-YYYY", "HR":"DD-MM-YYYY", "HU":"DD-MM-YYYY", "IE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "IS":"DD-MM-YYYY", "IT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "LT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "LV":"DD-MM-YYYY", "NL":"DD-MM-YYYY", "NO":"DD-MM-YYYY", "PL":"DD-MM-YYYY", "PT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "RO":"DD-MM-YYYY", "RS":"DD-MM-YYYY", "SE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "SI":"DD-MM-YYYY", "SK":"DD-MM-YYYY", "RU":"DD-MM-YYYY", "US":"NO", "PR":"NO", "CA":"NO", "AU":"NO", "NZ":"NO", "JP":"NO", "IN":"DD-MM-YYYY", "PH":"NO", "GB":"NO", "CN":"YYYY-MM-DD"}
    CTY_origin:{"SG":"FP", "AT":"PI", "BE":"PI", "BG":"PI", "CH":"PI", "CY":"PI", "CZ":"PI", "DE":"PI", "DK":"PI", "DO":"PI", "ES":"PI", "FI":"PI", "FR":"PI", "GR":"PI", "HR":"PI", "HU":"PI", "IE":"PI", "IS":"PI", "IT":"PI", "LT":"PI", "LV":"PI", "NL":"PI", "NO":"PI", "PL":"PI", "PT":"PI", "RO":"PI", "RS":"PI", "SE":"PI", "SI":"PI", "SK":"PI", "RU":"NO", "US":"FP", "PR":"FP", "CA":"FP", "AU":"NO", "NZ":"NO", "JP":"FP", "IN":"NO", "PH":"NO", "GB":"NO", "CN":"FP"}

    prob=LpProblem('RU per cluster') #Eventually it is a LpMaximize optimization. The objective will be set to maximize CTY volume, or number of selling units, or sales share, etc. per cluster
    x_cr=LpVariable.dicts('x',[(c, r) for c in clusters for r in CTY], 0, 1, LpBinary)
    prob+=lpSum([language_space[l]*x_cr[(c, r)] for c in clusters for r in CTY for l in language if l in CTY_language[r]])
    for c in clusters:
        prob+=lpSum([language_space[l]*x_cr[(c, r)] for r in CTY for l in language if l in CTY_language[r]])<=max_language_space
    for r in CTY:
        prob+=lpSum(x_cr[(c, r)] for c in clusters)==1
```

Comment: this is a terribly confusing question.  You probably need to edit the question or distill it down to a specific issue.  Your problem is not well described.  It isn't clear what a "cluster" is or how it relates to a label.  It seems you have rules to be able to figure out all possible clusters in advance....  What makes them dynamic?
You could either add a lot of info to your question (with some examples that encompass the decisions in the model) or distill it down to a toy example that exemplifies the core thing you are having trouble with.

Comment: @AirSquid thanks for the comment - I have edited the question to make it clearer, and it is a lot of information, so hard to squeeze it down without going into long explanations :) If the question/problem is still not clear - I will try and create a toy example as suggested.

Comment: It isn't clear why you don't just make a set of clusters that contain all the mutually compatible countries and pick from that set of clusters.  So if you had A-H countries you would get something like { {A, B, D, F}, {C, G}, {E}, {H}} for 4 cluster options and pick as needed.

Comment: @AirSquid Main reason is to try and have a more flexible automated model, as I have only added a third of the constraints in the example and half the countries, so wished to exclude any manual pre-set grouping and just run clustering optimization with listed constraints. But definitely, I can manually pre-group countries that share requirements and cluster inside each group and hope there is a solution for a better way.

Comment: Well, you can do some coding to make the groups, which is not an optimization problem.  I don't see any downside to constructing the groups and using this set of best groups for everything unless I'm missing something.  Why would you not?  If you had to "cover" country A & E from my previous example, you would just use the group 0 and group 2 clusters and be done, right?  And as a bonus, it would also cover B, D, F.

Comment: Do the characteristics of a "cluster" change in some way or are they static?  Meaning:  I think you desire to group countries with similar characteristics and it will produce a "cluster" with some "language space" based on the language, and that is fixed and then you are going to see how many clusters of different space you can fit on the label...but the cluster itself is static.  Is that right?

Comment: Clusters are not static. As I mentioned in the question a cluster=a label. If we take the example from previous comment and say max label space is 3. Then group 1, 2, 3 would stay the same, but group 0 can have many combos to meet the restriction [(A), (B, D, F)] [(B) (A, D, F)] [(D) (B, A, F)] [(A, B, D) (F)] [(A, B) (D, F)] etc. then based on the maximization criteria best combination will be chosen. So larger groups are static, but the clusters/labels are not.

Comment: oh man.  Just when I thought I had it figured out.  So my new understanding:  on any label, you can only include countries that have the same format, and you are limited by the total size, some languages require more size.  Presumably, you are not worried about language differences?  And no countries that have a different format can be included on the label?

Comment: If this is wrong, perhaps you could mock up an example label/cluster in the body of the question

Comment: You got the logic right! Languages do make a slight difference for a few countries, but they are overruled by the logistic set-up, which I didn't include in the question, as I thought if I can find a principal way of clustering countries based on a couple constraints, then the rest shouldn't be an issue to set up. In the meantime, I updated the model by creating larger groups of countries that share requirements and built it into the optimization model, so it works, the only thing left is to add logistic set-up, which would mean another pre-set sub-group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  Now that we have a better idea of the structure of the problem, here is a framework that I think will help you out.

The first part of the code makes groups from your data, excluding language.  The model portion assigns countries and groups to labels, with some constraints that are labeled.  Basically only 1 group is allowed per label and I put in an artificial constraint so that each group can only be used once to force the model to use multiple groups.

You didn't have any info in your model about why you would prefer one country over the other on any particular label (I'm assuming that is going to be handled elsewhere), so I just put in an objective to maximize the number of countries placed.  Seems to work, it draws from the biggest group to fit the biggest label, etc.

##### Code

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pulp import *

CTY=["SG", "AT", "BE", "BG", "CH", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GR", "HR", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LT", "LV", "NL", "NO", "PL", "PT", "RO", "RS", "SE", "SI", "SK", "RU", "US", "PR", "CA", "AU", "NZ", "JP", "IN", "PH", "GB", "CN"]
language=["EN_GB", "BG_BG", "CS_CZ", "DA_DK", "DE_DE", "EL_GR", "EN_GB", "ES_ES", "FI_FI", "FR_FR", "HR_HR", "HU_HU", "IT_IT", "LT_LT", "LV_LV", "NL_NL", "NO_NO", "PL_PL", "PT_PT", "RO_RO", "SK_SK", "SL_SI", "SR_RS", "SV_SE", "RU_RU", "EN_US", "EN_CA", "FR_CA", "EN_AU", "JA_JP", "EN_AU", "EN_IN", "EN_PH", "ZH_CN"]
BBD=["DD-MM-YYYY", "DD-ABC-YYYY", "YYYY/AB/DD", "YYYY-MM-DD"]
production_date=["DD-MM-YYYY", "YYYY-MM-DD", "NO"]
origin=["FP", "PI", "NO"]
space=[1, 2, 3]
max_language_space=5 #Main constraint - maximum allowed space for label. Value can change depending on the size of product.
#clusters=np.arange(1, 12) #Number of clusters are a consequence to meet an optimal solution - aim to have as little number of clusters as possible at an optimal solution.
CTY_BBD={"SG":"DD-MM-YYYY", "AT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "BE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "BG":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CH":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CY":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CZ":"DD-MM-YYYY", "DE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "DK":"DD-MM-YYYY", "DO":"DD-MM-YYYY", "ES":"DD-MM-YYYY", "FI":"DD-MM-YYYY", "FR":"DD-MM-YYYY", "GR":"DD-MM-YYYY", "HR":"DD-MM-YYYY", "HU":"DD-MM-YYYY", "IE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "IS":"DD-MM-YYYY", "IT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "LT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "LV":"DD-MM-YYYY", "NL":"DD-MM-YYYY", "NO":"DD-MM-YYYY", "PL":"DD-MM-YYYY", "PT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "RO":"DD-MM-YYYY", "RS":"DD-MM-YYYY", "SE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "SI":"DD-MM-YYYY", "SK":"DD-MM-YYYY", "RU":"DD-MM-YYYY", "US":"DD-ABC-YYYY", "PR":"DD-ABC-YYYY", "CA":"YYYY/AB/DD", "AU":"DD-MM-YYYY", "NZ":"DD-MM-YYYY", "JP":"YYYY-MM-DD", "IN":"DD-MM-YYYY", "PH":"DD-ABC-YYYY", "GB":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CN":"YYYY-MM-DD"}
language_space={"EN_GB":1, "BG_BG":1, "CS_CZ":1, "DA_DK":1, "DE_DE":1, "EL_GR":1, "EN_GB":1, "ES_ES":1, "FI_FI":1, "FR_FR":1, "HR_HR":1, "HU_HU":1, "IT_IT":1, "LT_LT":1, "LV_LV":1, "NL_NL":1, "NO_NO":1, "PL_PL":1, "PT_PT":1, "RO_RO":1, "SK_SK":1, "SL_SI":1, "SR_RS":1, "SV_SE":1, "RU_RU":3, "EN_US":1, "EN_CA":1, "FR_CA":1, "EN_AU":1, "JA_JP":3, "EN_AU":1, "EN_IN":1, "EN_PH":1, "ZH_CN":2}
CTY_language={"SG":["EN_GB"], "AT":["DE_DE"], "BE":["FR_FR", "NL_NL"], "BG":["BG_BG"], "CH":["DE_DE", "FR_FR"], "CY":["EL_GR"], "CZ":["CS_CZ"], "DE":["DE_DE"], "DK":["DA_DK"], "DO":["ES_ES"], "ES":["ES_ES"], "FI":["FI_FI"], "FR":["FR_FR"], "GR":["EL_GR"], "HR":["HR_HR"], "HU":["HU_HU"], "IE":["EN_GB"], "IS":["FI_FI", "SV_SE"], "IT":["IT_IT"], "LT":["LT_LT"], "LV":["LV_LV"], "NL":["NL_NL"], "NO":["NO_NO"], "PL":["PL_PL"], "PT":["PT_PT"], "RO":["RO_RO"], "RS":["SR_RS"], "SE":["SV_SE"], "SI":["SL_SI"], "SK":["SK_SK"], "RU":["RU_RU"], "US":["EN_US"], "PR":["EN_US"], "CA":["EN_CA", "FR_CA"], "AU":["EN_AU"], "NZ":["EN_AU"], "JP":["JA_JP"], "IN":["EN_IN"], "PH":["EN_PH"], "GB":["EN_GB"], "CN":["ZH_CN"]}
CTY_production_date={"SG":"DD-MM-YYYY", "AT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "BE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "BG":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CH":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CY":"DD-MM-YYYY", "CZ":"DD-MM-YYYY", "DE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "DK":"DD-MM-YYYY", "DO":"DD-MM-YYYY", "ES":"DD-MM-YYYY", "FI":"DD-MM-YYYY", "FR":"DD-MM-YYYY", "GR":"DD-MM-YYYY", "HR":"DD-MM-YYYY", "HU":"DD-MM-YYYY", "IE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "IS":"DD-MM-YYYY", "IT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "LT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "LV":"DD-MM-YYYY", "NL":"DD-MM-YYYY", "NO":"DD-MM-YYYY", "PL":"DD-MM-YYYY", "PT":"DD-MM-YYYY", "RO":"DD-MM-YYYY", "RS":"DD-MM-YYYY", "SE":"DD-MM-YYYY", "SI":"DD-MM-YYYY", "SK":"DD-MM-YYYY", "RU":"DD-MM-YYYY", "US":"NO", "PR":"NO", "CA":"NO", "AU":"NO", "NZ":"NO", "JP":"NO", "IN":"DD-MM-YYYY", "PH":"NO", "GB":"NO", "CN":"YYYY-MM-DD"}
CTY_origin={"SG":"FP", "AT":"PI", "BE":"PI", "BG":"PI", "CH":"PI", "CY":"PI", "CZ":"PI", "DE":"PI", "DK":"PI", "DO":"PI", "ES":"PI", "FI":"PI", "FR":"PI", "GR":"PI", "HR":"PI", "HU":"PI", "IE":"PI", "IS":"PI", "IT":"PI", "LT":"PI", "LV":"PI", "NL":"PI", "NO":"PI", "PL":"PI", "PT":"PI", "RO":"PI", "RS":"PI", "SE":"PI", "SI":"PI", "SK":"PI", "RU":"NO", "US":"FP", "PR":"FP", "CA":"FP", "AU":"NO", "NZ":"NO", "JP":"FP", "IN":"NO", "PH":"NO", "GB":"NO", "CN":"FP"}

# group the countries by key properties
groupings = defaultdict(list)

# and the space required, indexed by country
space_reqd = dict()

for c in CTY:
    # get the language...  Not clear what to do with multiple languages
    # as the language affects the space requirement.  We'll just pick the "first"
    language = CTY_language[c][0]
    space_reqd[c] = language_space[language]

    # gather the properties as a key
    properties = (CTY_BBD[c], CTY_origin[c], CTY_production_date[c])

    # add this country to the list with these properties
    groupings[properties].append(c)

print(f'Grouping resulted in {len(groupings)} groups')

# let's make some fake labels with space parameter
label_sizes = {  'soda': 3,
                 'salad': 4,
                 'bread': 2,
                 'cereal': 7}

M = max(len(v) for v in groupings.values())

# now we can set up the problem
prob = LpProblem('label_maker', sense=LpMaximize)

# some convenience sets
grps = groupings.keys()
lbls = label_sizes.keys()
ctry_lbl = [(ctry, lbl) for ctry in CTY for lbl in lbls]
grp_lbl  = [(grp,  lbl) for grp in grps for lbl in lbls]

place = LpVariable.dicts('place', ctry_lbl, cat=LpBinary)        # place country on label
assign_group = LpVariable.dicts('group', grp_lbl, cat=LpBinary)  # assign group to label

# keep within max size, for each label
for lbl in lbls:
    prob += lpSum(place[ctry, lbl] for ctry in CTY) <= label_sizes[lbl]

# only 1 group per label
for lbl in lbls:
    prob += lpSum(assign_group[grp, lbl] for grp in grps) <= 1

# link the selection of a country to the group, for each label
for grp, lbl in grp_lbl:
    prob += assign_group[grp, lbl] * M >= lpSum(place[ctry, lbl] for ctry in groupings[grp])


# some fake constraint to not reuse groups...this is just to exercise the model
for grp in grps:
    prob += lpSum(assign_group[grp, lbl] for lbl in lbls) <= 1

# objective:  maximize the countries placed
prob += lpSum(place[ctry, lbl] for (ctry, lbl) in ctry_lbl)

#print(prob)

solution = prob.solve()

print(solution)

for ctry, lbl in sorted(ctry_lbl, key = lambda x: x[1]):
    if place[ctry, lbl].varValue:
        print(f'place {ctry} on label {lbl}')

for grp, lbl in sorted(grp_lbl, key = lambda x: x[1]):
    if assign_group[grp, lbl].varValue:
        print(f'label {lbl} utilizes group format: {grp}')
```

##### Output

```
Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                14.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.01
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.01   (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

1
place US on label bread
place PR on label bread
place GR on label cereal
place HR on label cereal
place HU on label cereal
place IS on label cereal
place IT on label cereal
place PL on label cereal
place SI on label cereal
place RU on label salad
place IN on label salad
place AU on label soda
place NZ on label soda
place GB on label soda
label bread utilizes group format: ('DD-ABC-YYYY', 'FP', 'NO')
label cereal utilizes group format: ('DD-MM-YYYY', 'PI', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
label salad utilizes group format: ('DD-MM-YYYY', 'NO', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
label soda utilizes group format: ('DD-MM-YYYY', 'NO', 'NO')
```

Comment: I have a follow up question, but first wanted to say thanks for the support! I am struggling with logistic flows. How would you tackle the following: all CTY are linked to fixed flows, but when those flows are layered on top of labels multiple scenarios arise. Let's take BG,RO,HU,HR,SK,RS share same flow. If label is large, these CTYs + other n CTYs under fixed flows can be part of one label. If the label is small, we can have up to 3 unique labels linked to the same flow. I was thinking of adding an additional decision variable, but cannot link it to the above model. Any thoughts?

Comment: The relationship you loosely describe above is (again) pretty confusing.  It isn't clear how "logistic flows" are linked to layered labels and multiple labels.  Try a couple things out.  It sounds like you may need another *index* for your decision variable